# SqlHelper.ExecuteReader Function that executes a stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am messing up somewhere when writing a function to execute stored procedure. I think i don't have an idea how to execute SqlHelper.ExecuteReader. in SQL server 2005

This should return the state name. But i get it empty. Any idea, why??

Thanks in advance :)

```
reader = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(DbConnString, System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetStateName", parameters);
while (reader.Read())
    StateName = reader["StateName"].ToString();
return StateName;
```

and the stored proc:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStateName](
@StateInitials varchar
)

AS 

Begin

SELECT StateName FROM StateList WHERE StateInitials=@StateInitials

End
```

Comment: if you can give your sql stored proc and what parameters you are passing, it would be helpful to answer.

Comment: GetStateName is the stored Procedure!!

Comment: I did add storedproc. Thanks for all your help. i really appreciate it!!

Comment: If you run the stored procedure manually from sql DB, does it return proper results? If yes, then the problem could be the way you are passing sql parameters

Comment: Can you show us how you are declaring/setting `parameters`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess that the value you're passing to the SP for @StateInitials has more than one character, but because you've not specified the size of the varchar parameter (eg, varchar(25)), the value is being truncated to just one character, and therefore there are no matches.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx)

> When n is not specified in a data
>   definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1.